# Azure Policy Evaluation triggers - Issues with On-demand evaluation scan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring, azure-policy

As I'm working on implementating policies (especially on App Services Plan and WebApp), I need to  quickly test new rules for my policies. I tried to launch the on-demand scan on my resources with a REST API POST command using the following URI structures:

`POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.PolicyInsights/policyStates/latest/triggerEvaluation?api-version=2018-07-01-preview`

cf. https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/governance/policy/how-to/get-compliance-data

The call returns a 202 Accepted status (=seems good :) ):

[image]

**Issue : But when I check the Compliance board in the Azure portal, no scan was done.**

1. I'm wondering if on-demand scanning is only available for certain azure services (such as storage account in the example, see shared link above) and not for others such as WebApp, Service Plan etc)
2. I'm also wondering if the on-demand scan will trigger the policy evaluation at the same time (even if the effect is different : Deny effect VS deployIfNotExists effect for example) ?

Has anyone ever encountered this kind of issues with on-demand policies evaluation scan ? :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kemley noted, the portal will not reflect until the compliance scan is finished. In my experience, it can take a few minutes for portal to reflect the updates.

This Microsoft Blog here does a good summary on the time it takes for the Policy Evaluation Scans: https://msftplayground.com/2019/06/on-demand-azure-policy-scan/

Below is a snippet from that article.

> The evaluation of the policies take place on the following events:
>
> ```
> * New policy assignment. ( ~30 minutes).
> * Updated assignment of a existing policy. (~ 30 minutes)
> * Deployment of a resources. (~15 minutes)
> * Every 24 hours
> * Update of the resource provider
> * On-demand (~3 minutes)
> ```

You can also find the scan time estimates burried in the official Microsoft Azure Docs here (but it's not as nicely bullet-pointed as the above link): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/get-compliance-data#evaluation-triggers

For the on-demand evaluation scan calling the REST API, the 202 Accepted status is indicating the Scan was triggered, but doesn't mean it has completed yet.

You will receive an HTTP 200 status code when the scan is complete. When you trigger the scan, the response message will include a URI in the Location field of the response header message. This URI is what you can query to check for the scan status (HTTP 202 you can interpret as scan is still running, and HTTP 200 is scan complete).

My experience is that all the policy effects were evaluated and returned by the time the status scan shows completed but I do not see official documentation on this. Also, my experience is that compliance results to reflect in the Portal will sometimes take up to another additional 3 to 5 minutes for Portal (this I speculate is dependent upon the size of the environment/scope of the scans), but Microsoft does not provide specific SLAs on that at this time either.

Microsoft has recently provided a Azure CLI and Azure PowerShell commands to trigger on-demand policy evaluation scans. Those commands are documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/how-to/get-compliance-data#on-demand-evaluation-scan

Answer (score 1):

The compliance results are not updated on the portal until the compliance scan is finished so there will a bit of time between launching the scan and seeing the results in Portal.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the actual state for a subscription with
`az policy state trigger-scan`.